# determine if user is logged in via ajax call and proper return values (Magento 1.4)

Tags: ajax, magento-1.4, customer-session

We have a product setup where a user may spend some time configuring a product. The configuration is done via an API and in theory they could be logged out due to inactivity.

I want to implement the following logic when the click "share"

- send a request to the controller that returns a simple `{login:1}` or `{login:0}`
- if logged in, save the product to their wishlist and popup a modal saying that it's been added
- if not logged in, redirect them to the login page with a return url specified.

I thought it helpful to give a strategic overview. but specific question is two parts:

1. what is the best controller url to use (something like `/customer/session/checklogin`) to route the request to.
2. Is there a method in a class that already checks this in some way?  If so let me know.  I don't mind copying from app/core to app/local and creating a new simple method

Answer (score 3):

The URL for you request should be unique. But if you are using a custom module (and for this I think you have to)  it can't be `customer` since that leads to the `Mage_Customer` module.

For checking if a user is logged in use the following function which returns a boolean

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()
```